# The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request during the api calls

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Our application is running successfully in client environment but sometimes facing the below exception during the api calls.

> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was
> canceled.  ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the
> transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of
> either a thread exit or an application request..  --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been
> aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Code: (Asp.net core c# language)

```cs
Class A 
{
    private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    public async Task<string> CallServiceAsync(string url, string jsonData)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: One reason could be the httpClient is timing out. Are you getting the taskcanceled exception after around 20 sec from making the request?

Comment: @SharathNS thanks for the response. we didn't know that how many seconds after getting this exception. we will add the logs to find out it. But if it would have happened due to timeout, we had the timeout exception in log right?

Comment: Doesn't this exception occur simply when client closes the application during request?

Comment: @freakish That's what I would have thought, too. But this code does not suggest that could be the case, does it? @viji: is the same `httpClient` accessed anywhere else?

Comment: Is the (or better are all) call to this method awaited?

Comment: @freakish We couldn't identify when, why it is happening. Randomly facing this exception not for every request.

Comment: In that case: Add logging to identify possible patterns in the request data that may be correlated to the exception or lack thereof which may hint at different reasons.

Comment: Maybe also add resilience (either manual or Polly)? This won't get you to the reason why it happens but it can make your app more robust. The behavior when retrying for example can also provide hints as to why this happens.

Comment: @Fildor this httpclient used only here. calling methods are awaited.

Comment: There is no way for us to diagnose transient errors in your code on your client's infrastructure. You need to add logging and inspect the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `using` to dispose the response (which you are ignoring for some reason). Eventually the response times out (because you haven't read it or closed it) and throws an exception

```cs
public async Task<string> CallServiceAsync(string url, string jsonData)
{
    using HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return SomethingHere; // why was this missing?
}
```

Normally you would actually do stuff with the response. For example:

```cs
public async Task<string> CallServiceAsync(string url, string jsonData)
{
    using HttpContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return result.
}
```